# Override table cell background color in highcharts-tooltip

Tags: css, highcharts, tooltip, overriding, splunk

I'm creating Splunk dashboards. For my tables I have a style sheet called application.css that alternates the color of the table rows, per requirements. Unfortunately when using charts the highcharts-tooltip is basically a table and it is rendered with alternating colors for the rows. As a result the value row is a very light green background with white text. The text cannot be read.

It looks like the highcharts-tooltip is generated by a java script.

This is how the tooltip is rendered in the page:

```
<table class="highcharts-tooltip">
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: left; color: rgb(204, 204, 204); max-width: 120.34px;">    WebPage:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: right; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); max-width: 504.65px;">\\x94/bla/bla/Browse.html\\x94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: left; color: rgb(30, 147, 198); max-width: 120.34px;">Hits:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: right; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); max-width: 504.65px;">12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: left; color: rgb(30, 147, 198); max-width: 120.34px;">Hits%:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="text-align: right; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); max-width: 504.65px;">24.49%</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The second tr is the one that cannot be read. My question is, is there a way to override the alternating row colors in the tooltip using css in my application.css file so that the row is not rgb(255,255,255) but rgb(00,00,00)?

Comment: You don't describe how you are generating your highcharts code but here is the API doc on how to format your tooltip: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip

Comment: The highcharts are generated within the Splunk package. I have no control over their generation. the best I can do is to try to override the css style.

Comment: Second `tr` or every second `td`?

Answer (score 3):

Using `!important` might be the only way of overriding the in-line style. Keep in mind this solution will change the color of td even in tooltips of other charts. Prepend the selector with the `#[CHART CONTAINER ID]` to avoid that.

Css:

```
table.highcharts-tooltip tbody tr td:nth-child(2){
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```

[nth-child browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Browser_compatibility)